# In analysis can I swap $\epsilon$ with any other value if I can prove that value tends to zero, or can represent any other value on the number line

Tags: real-analysis

The query arose when I was looking at a standard convergent series questions. I have  been given a convergent series. therefore I know it is Cauchy, and I already know that lim of the terms  converges to zero.

The proof then wants me to show that $\lim (n*x_{n})=0$. I know there are other ways to do this but it would be so much easier if could substitute $\epsilon$ with $\epsilon'=\epsilon/n$.

Therefore for every $n\geq M$, there exists $\epsilon'$ such that $\epsilon'>|x_{n}|$. From here the proof is obvious.

My two question are.

1st, when I change epsilon form being just an arbitrary number to a combination of an arbitrary number and a number/value that has a property what must I ensure that to check to make sure this proof doesn't fall apart. I assume that I must show that $\lim \frac{\epsilon}{n}\rightarrow0$

2nd, is the fact that n has a changing value make this impossible.

Too me I feel as if I am within my right to do this, and from pervious propositions I know that If I can prove that |bn|<an and $\lim a_{n}\rightarrow 0$ then $|b_{n}|$ converges to zero and so does $b_{n}$ and therefore as long as I can prove that the new epsilon goes to zero i am clear.

My major concern is my book says this problem is challenging which makes me think that there must be something more.

I was also told that the sequence is decreasing however I don't see how that impacts the question at all if I go about my proof.

P.S

I would like to flesh out question 2 here. what I mean is that $\epsilon'$ and $|X_{n}|$ can both respectively change as n changes. therefore $\epsilon'$ is not a fixed value and therefore I don't know that I can say that for all $n\geq M$ that $\epsilon'>|x_{n}|$. If we just think about  the term after the first one that stratifies this property $\epsilon'$ can decrease in such a way that $|x_{n+1}|$ does not have this property but eventually. The fact that epsilon is not fixed worries me in this proof.

Comment: Your new $\varepsilon$ depends on $n$, so the proposed change doesn’t work. Remember: the definition of a limit equaling $0$ is that for each $\varepsilon>0$ (this implies that it is fixed), there is a corresponding $N(\varepsilon)$ such that $n>N(\varepsilon)$ guarantees the sequence is with $\varepsilon$ of the limiting value, in this case, $0$.

Comment: thank you so much, I just fleshed out that thought in the post script. I thought that a non fixed epsilon blew up the proof. It is good for that to be confirmed

Comment: Also, if you are only using that the limit of terms converges to zero, then $x_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ is a counterexample. Somehow you must use not just that the limit of terms converges to zero, but that the series itself converges.

Comment: I'm not convinced that $nx_n \to 0$ for every convergent series. What series were you given?

Comment: When proving something that involves the statement "for **all** $\epsilon >0$," there's something fundamentally fishy about a proof that says "there exists **some** $\epsilon'$ ... ."